ERC721 NFT is empty in Avalanche Fuji Testnet
I am using OpenZeppelin to generate this simple contract and Remix IDE to deploy it and interact with it using Core Wallet as injected provider:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
    
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.2/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.2/access/Ownable.sol";
    
contract HelloAvax is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 private _nextTokenId;
    
    constructor(address initialOwner)
            ERC721("HelloAvax", "HVA")
            Ownable(initialOwner)
    {}
    
    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link";
    }
    
    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}

The NFT is minted but without image and no metadata. I removed the extension of the metadata file as the Avalanche official tutorials indicate, here the _BASEURI:
https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link
Here an example of minted NFT: https://testnet.snowtrace.io/nft/0x3F10c7e20922CCD0f1f3f10aE98c502aEc40a1F4/0?chainId=43113

You need to append the _baseURI with /:
https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link/

Because the tokenId is getting appended to the _baseURI in order to form the corresponding tokenURI, like:
tokenURI(tokenId) => baseURI + tokenId


tokenURI(0) => https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link/0

tokenURI(1) => https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link/1

...

In your case:
_baseURI = https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link

Therefore, the derived tokenURI having tokenId as 0 would be:
tokenURI(0) => https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link0

which is not pointing to a valid metadata.
So, the revised _baseURI() function should be:
function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "https://bafybeibodhnumbvvzjtplwzxomddz53jmgejb4eezv7ii6kw5py6c2rnya.ipfs.dweb.link/";
}

Here's an example of minted NFT after revising the _baseURI() function:
https://testnet.snowtrace.io/nft/0xf84bC3F571B851FfdA1a6e45f537e529d945F1E1/0?chainId=43113
Additionally you need to use this compiler version: 0.8.24+commit.e11b9ed9

Didn't work, anyway, thank you.

@JoseMiguelVegaLopez, I've revised my answer. Please check.

I am still getting an empty NFT: https://testnet.snowtrace.io/nft/0xAfaE2e692aC2b94876Ca74d852A2DB8d4E87Da9C/0?chainId=43113
Did you use exactly the same contract but just appending the "/"? I am using Remix for deploying and Core Wallet as the injected provider.

@JoseMiguelVegaLopez, yes the exact same contract by just appending the / to the _baseURI. I've also just verified it. You can also match the code. I'm using Remix for deploying and MetaMask Wallet as injected provider.

Thanks a lot for your help beast. For some reason, my contracts are not verified after deploying using Remix. I saw your contract has the green checkmark in Snowtrace, mine not. Do you know what can be the issue? I am using a recently created Core wallet with just Testnet Avax

The compiler version did the trick, problem solved!

The green checkmark is for the verified status of the contract. You can verify your contract in Remix using the Etherscan plugin.

You're welcome, @JoseMiguelVegaLopez. Happy coding!
